# How do I get "Solution Files" to the drops build folder using VSO Build or otherwise

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, azure-devops

I'm using **Visual Studio Online** and the **hosted build controller**, I have a automated build working and putting output in the drops folder in **TFS Online**.

I'm using Team Foundation Version Control and the Default Template (DefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml)

I'm using the MSBuild Arguments to generate project specific output 
`/p:GenerateProjectSpecificOutputFolder=true`

My solution has a number of projects and a MVC Web Application.

In the solution I've added a solution folder and placed some powershell files in there. I would like these powershell files to end up in the Drops folder after an automated build.

Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Comment: What version of TFS are you using? The v12 build templates in TFS 2013+ allow a custom PS build step that could copy those. If you are stuck on v11, you could let a project file copy them as a post build step.

Comment: @DaveShaw - Visual Studio Online - Hosted Build Controller

Answer (score 0):

You should switch to the TfvcDefaultTemplate.12.xaml. You can then create a PowerShell that scoops up the bits you need in your drop and call it from the post-test PowerShell activity.

Check out the "gather items for drops" on https://curah.microsoft.com/8047/run-scripts-in-your-team-foundation-build-process

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, any links or starters on how this can be done?

Comment: There is a dropdown list at the top of the Build Definition Process tab.